# click() method not working Console returning error JavaScript

Tags: javascript, methods, error-handling, click

I'm Trying to create a set of actions with the click of a "Button B"

 which will click on "Button A" as the last action of the function triggered by B.
 I have used the same line of code elsewhere. I can't figure out why I keep getting errors for the last action call.

Please help me understand I have researched quite a bit can't find an answer.

```js
function doActionsA(){
  document.getElementById('view').innerHTML = "You clicked?";
}

function doActionsB(){
//Other actions befor the click action.

//I used this befor and it worked in other instances
document.getElementsByClassName('active').click();
}
```

```html
<div id="view"></div>
<button class="active" onclick="doActionsA();">Button A</button>
<button class="trigger" onclick="doActionsB();"> Button B</button>
```

Comment: *//I used this befor and it worked in other instances* . *//No you didn't that will always throw an error*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements. So you need to acces individual element and then perform click operation

```js
function doActionsA(){
  document.getElementById('view').innerHTML = "You clicked?";
}

function doActionsB(){
//Other actions befor the click action.

//I used this befor and it worked in other instances
document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].click();
}
```

```html
<div id="view"></div>
<button class="active" onclick="doActionsA();">Button A</button>
<button class="trigger" onclick="doActionsB();"> Button B</button>
```